# Events order for Spring Cloud Stream Reactive using Kafka binder

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We are using Spring Cloud Stream reactive with the kafka binder and we would like to ask if it can be possible to consume multiple events from the same partition in parallel.
See the code sample posted bellow:

```
    @Bean
    public Function<Flux<Event1, Event2> eventProcessor() {
        return flux -> flux
                .doOnNext(e -> log.info("Event consumed: " + e)
                .flatMap(e -> {
                    if (e instanceof Event11 e11)
                        return reactiveRepo.save(e11)
                    } else {
                        return Mono.just(e);
                    })
                .map(e -> mapToExternalEvent(e));
    }
```

Imagine that the kafka topic we consumes from contains e1, e2 and e3 in the same partiton and only e1 is of type *Event11*. It means that for e1 our pipeline will call *reactiveRepo.save()* and no IO operations will be executed for e2 and e3.

**Quesiton**: Can we consider that e2 and e3 will not be processed before the *mapToExternalEvent(e)* is processed for e1? Can it happen that because of the IO operation for e1, the pipeline can process e2 faster and to emit an external event for e2 faster than e1? Does it make sense to change the flatMap() with concatMap() given that we would like to process event from different partitions in any order?

In our case each event from the inbound channel will result to an event to the outbound channel. We would like to make sure that the order of the external events we produce will correspond to the order of the events being consumed.